# JTable tracking when the user makes a cell change and only the user

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am working on my first Java/Swing application and I need some help with the JTable.

The problem I am having is that I want to track when a USER makes edits to my JTable and NOT the application. I did the following:

```
//Made my table then did the following line:

table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);

//Have a listener set up:

public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(e);
 }
```

Now the problem is I do not want this to fire when my program does changes to the Table, for example I load a new table and the file I loaded had 15 rows then I would get 15 different events firing. I only want to fire an even when the USER made an edit to a cell.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not add the `TableModelListener` _after_ the table is populated?

Comment: The table can be populated at any given time with a new row,a row deletion or the user loading a new file so that would not be a solution for my application.

Comment: So either remove the TML before the user action (that refreshes the entire table) and add it again after it has ended, or set a flag in the code that indicates that programmatic changes are happening.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that Andrew, but was hoping there would be a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's comment has some of the most common ways to handle this situation.  Depending on how your model is constructed/stored and what exactly you want to do on a change you could have something fire in the model when changed, or possible under the setValueAt method.